# Android library component

Tags: android, user-interface, components

I'm trying to make a reusable component that slides its content.

Here is the code of the component :

```
package com.example.components;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class SlideRightNLeft extends LinearLayout{



private LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1;
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2;


public SlideRightNLeft(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SlideRightNLeft(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SlideRightNLeft(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}



public void slideRight(){
    int x = 0;

    while(x < 300) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.getChildAt(0).getWidth(), this.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
        params1.setMargins(300 - x, 1, 1, 1);

        params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.getChildAt(0).getWidth(), this.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
        params2.setMargins(x, 1, 1, 1);

        this.getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(params1);

        this.getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(params2);

        x++;
        this.invalidate();

    }
}


}
```

Unfortunately it won't slide. In can suppose I have to use `runOnUiThread` to actually see it slide, but it needs an activity, and as I am in the component, I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Context` thats passed into the constructor to access the `runOnUiThread` method.

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

});
```

Comment: I did try but eclipse send me an error saying 'The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type Context' ... You have to pass an activity.

Comment: cast the context to an Activity and use the method. See the edited post.